# Beautiful code in prototype, how to omit 'is not a function' errors on empty result selectors

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I do this in jQuery and `li.notsuchelem` don't exist

```
$('li.notsuchelem').closest('div')
```

it works fine

But when I do same thing in Prototype it gives me an error

```
$$('li.notsuchelem').up('div')

>TypeError: $$('li.notsuchelem').up is not a function
```

how can I make beautiful code from this:

```
if ($$('li.notsuchelem').length) $$('li.notsuchelem').up('div');

>>>>

var tmp;
if ((tmp = $$('li.notsuchelem')).length) tmp.up('div');

>>>>

$$('li.notsuchelem').each(function(el){el.up('div')});
```

All is looks ugly to me in opposite to jQuery way. Is there something I can do with it or I just must deal with it?

---

well, I think I will accept the answer, but either I'm coding wrong or I just don't like Prototype

jQuery:

```
$('.ss_new:not(.force_visible)', wrapper).closest('tr').hide();
```

Prototype:

```
wrapper.select('.ss_new:not(.force_visible)').invoke('up','tr').invoke('hide');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes like this in prototypejs.

```
$$(".test").invoke("up", "div");
```

Comment: it seems like what i wanted, need to check docs for `invoke`. something like with `each`, but shorter and better looking

Answer (score 1):

Instead of length, you can coerce the returned array into a number. Moreover, you can use the side-effects of the logical AND (`&&`) operator.

```
+$$('li.notsuchelem') && $$('li.notsuchelem').up('div');
```

Comment: well, it's almost same as `if ($$('li.notsuchelem').length) $$('li.notsuchelem').up('div');`. little shorter. but i still call search twice and use some kind of `if`